# Session sharing between desktop and mobile website applications?

Tags: session, tomcat, mobile, web

I am wondering what the best way is to share authentication, session management, etc. across a web site with both a mobile and desktop version.  We are running Tomcat, and prefer to keep the mobile and the desktop sites separate applications on separate nodes.

I have seen similar posts regarding persisting the session throughout Tomcat applications, but I'd prefer to do this through the app alone.  I've read about clustering in Tomcat, but that appears to be for a single app running across many nodes.

Is there a common way to do this?  How do other sites handle session management across mobile and desktop versions?

Comment: I may be asking a painfully obvious question here, but why should mobile sessions be handled differently than desktop?  I can see rendering the view differently...but I'm having trouble figuring out why you would want to handle sessions differently.

Comment: I may have mis-explained it.  We do not need to handle the mobile session differently, just share it to the desktop version.  The equivalent of logging into a mobile site, then clicking the 'Full Site' link.

Comment: Are your mobile and desktop sites running in the same context, or completely different web servers?

Comment: Different web servers, but same domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly you are implementing you mobile and desktop versions of your site as separate web applications. Sharing sessions across multiple apps is not part of the j2ee specs as far as I know; in addition to that I am not aware of any product that offers the functionality..

..So, that would leave you with the option of implementing your own :)

one obvious approach would be to use the db to store session data instead of HttpSession; I'm not saying this is easy; actually may be a good reason to reconsider the decision of having two separate apps for the same site

Comment: Well we're essentially debating between clustering/valve in Tomcat or maybe using SSO.  So it looks like we have ways of using Tomcat functionality and not having to roll our own, but we are just unsure of what is considered best practice.

Comment: mmm... those options don't sound like natural fits to me: sso would be useful to flag sessions for multiple (distinct) apps as authenticated possibly sharing credentials information but it's intention is not really to share all the data in the session. clustering would be useful to deploy multiple copies of the same app in multiple instances of the server (possibly in order to scale horizontally).